# Flutter web redirect user if not authentiacted

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-web, flutter-getx

I have a GetMaterialApp with named routes to be used in Flutter web for a dashboard project. However, I am struggling to check whether the user is authenticated and redirect the user depending on the auth state. This is my App Code:

```
GetMaterialApp(
      initialBinding: InitialBinding(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: CustomTheme().getLightTheme,
      themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
      title: "----------",
      initialRoute: "/login",
      unknownRoute: GetPage(name: "/notfound", page: () => NotFoundPage()),
      getPages: [
        GetPage(name: "/login", page: () => Root()),
        GetPage(name: "/dashboard", page: () => Dashboard()),
      ],
    ),
```

I am using `GetX` to handle the authentication state. Therefore, I have access to the authentication state throughout the web app. The Root widget consists of a simple `Obx` to check the authentication state and send the user to the dashboard:

```
return Obx(() => (Get.find<AuthController>().loggedIn) ? Dashboard() : LoginScreen());
```

Sadly, that does not do the trick, as the url does not change, simply the content does. The url remains at /login.

I could simply call `Get.toNamed("dashboard")` when the user is logged in, but then the dashboard page would be exposed to the url, allowing the user to reach the /dashboard url even if he is not logged in.

I also do not want to create a check in every Widget or page I create, since that would be inefficient. Is there a way to check whether the user is logged in and, if not, redirect the user to the login page on every url entered?

Example:

- **[www.adress.com/dashboard](http://www.adress.com/dashboard)** would redirect to **[www.adress.com/login](http://www.adress.com/login)** if the user is not logged in

Is there a way to generally check the auth-state and redirect the user accordingly using `GetX`?

Side Note: I am able to get the correct authentication state **every time**, that is not the problem, as I use GetX.

**Short Summary:**
Is it possible to check the auth state outside the actual widget (e.g. in the GetMaterialApp) and redirect any not-authenticated users to the login page, even if they type in the /dashboard url?

Comment: You can use GetX Middleware: https://pub.dev/packages/get#getpage-middleware

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use middleware for check if user is authenticated or not

```
GetMaterialApp(
      initialBinding: InitialBinding(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: CustomTheme().getLightTheme,
      themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
      title: "----------",
      initialRoute: "/dashboard",
      unknownRoute: GetPage(name: "/notfound", page: () => NotFoundPage()),
      getPages: [
        GetPage(name: "/login", page: () => Root()),
        GetPage(name: "/dashboard", page: () => Dashboard(), middleware: [AuthMiddleware()]),
      ],
    ),

class AuthMiddlware extends Middlware {
   RouteSetting? redirect(String? route) => !isAuthenticated ? RouteSetting(name="/login") : null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just needed to change Middleware to GetMiddleware and RouteSetting to RouteSettings :)

Answer (score 4):

If the user requests an arbitrary page within your web app, then you may want to intercept with the login page before continuing to the requested page. You can do this by passing a return url to the login page...

main.dart

```
GetMaterialApp(
  ...
  initialRoute: "/dashboard",
  getPages: [
    GetPage(name: "/login", page: () => Root()),
    GetPage(
      name: "/dashboard", 
      page: () => Dashboard(), 
      middlewares: [AuthMiddleware()]
    ),
  ],
),

class AuthMiddleware extends GetMiddleware {
  RouteSettings? redirect(String? route) {
    String returnUrl = Uri.encodeFull(route ?? '');
    return !isAuthenticated
      ? RouteSettings(name: "/login?return=" + returnUrl)
      : null;
  }
}
```

Then in your login page, after logging in you can direct back to where the original request intended...

login.dart

```
    //after successful login...
    String returnUrl = Get.parameters['return'] ?? '/';
    Get.offAllNamed(returnUrl);
```